# »Eine Seite Wortschatz« oder »Eine Seite Wortschatzes«?

Tags: grammar, genitive

Wie bildet man den partitiv Genitiv in diesem Fall:

> Heute schicke ich dir eine Seite Wortschatz

Dies klingt mir am besten, ergibt aber nicht so viele Treffer beim Googlen. Und: fügt man ein Adjektiv hinzu,

> Heute schicke ich dir eine Seite notwendiger Wortschatz

so klingt es mir komisch (oder?). Oder ist folgende Variante richtig?

> Heute schicke ich dir eine Seite Wortschatzes.

Comment: Related (but does not answer it): http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11341/what-kind-of-construction-is-eine-tasse-kaffee/11343#11343

Comment: I see. Vielleicht setz mein Ausdruck irrtümlich voraus, dass *eine Seite* eine allgegenwärtige, wohl-bekannte Maßeinheit für Wortschatz ist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Heute schicke ich dir eine Seite Wortschatz

ist korrekt. Der Wortschatz steht hier im partitivischen Nominativ, der in [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11341/what-kind-of-construction-is-eine-tasse-kaffee/11343#11343) ausgiebiger diskutiert wird.

Wenn du den Wortschatz konkretisieren möchtest, also zum Beispiel ein Adjektiv oder einen Artikel dazuschreiben möchtest, musst du vom partitivischen Nominativ in einen partitivischen Dativ oder Genitiv wechseln:

> Heute schicke ich dir eine Seite **notwendigen Wortschatzes** (Genitiv)
>   Heute schicke ich dir eine Seite **von notwendigem Wortschatz** (Dativ)

Zu früheren Zeiten hätte man wohl *»Heute schicke ich dir eine Seite Wortschatzes«* gesagt, das ist aber heutzutage unüblich.

Die beiden Varianten unterscheiden Bedeutungsnuancen: Der Genitiv drückt implizit aus, dass *notwendiger Wortschatz* ein abgeschlossenes Ganzes ist. Das Ganze muss nicht stabil sein (es können Elemente hinzukommen oder entfernt werden), aber es muss irgendwie definiert sein. Der Dativ unterstellt, dass man eine vollständige Liste nicht aufstellen könnte. Vergleiche die Folgenden:

> Liste von Doktorarbeiten – (ziemlich viele Leute haben eine Doktorarbeit bestanden, es sollte also einige geben)
>   Liste der Doktorarbeiten an der chemischen Fakultät der Uni Hannover des Jahres 2014 – (diese Zahl ist überschaubar und ändert sich nicht)

Answer (score -1):

"Heute schicke ich Dir eine Seite (vom) Wortschatz(e)" wäre Dativ. Nicht schön, aber "legal". Man würde das eher bei z. B. einem Lebensmittel sagen:

> Ich kaufe mir eine Scheibe Käse.

Für den Genitiv ist der Artikel aber Pflicht:

> Heute schicke Dir eine Seite des Wortschatzes.

Comment: Ich find „eine Seite Wortschatzes“ ebenso richtig wie „ein(en) Becher Weines“.

Comment: Hier ist „Käse“ im Nominativ, nicht im Dativ. Siehe http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11341/what-kind-of-construction-is-eine-tasse-kaffee/11343#11343

Comment: "Für den Genitiv ist der Artikel aber Pflicht:" nicht unbedingt: "Ich trinke ein Glas guten Weines." "Ich esse eine Scheibe backofenfrischen Brotes." "Auf einen guten Satz kommen zehn Seiten lagweiliger Prosa."... in allen diesen Beispielen haben wir eine "Maßeinheit" gefolgt von einem artikellosen Genitivs eines als nicht zählbar aufgefassten Nomens. Ich stimme zu, dass es in OPs Beispiel nicht funktioniert, aber der Grund ist eher nicht der Genitiv. Ich glaube es liegt daran dass "Wortschatz" nicht teilbar ist.

Answer (score -1):

Besser klingt :

**Heute schicke ich dir eine Seite notwendiger Wortschätze.**

jedoch ist:

**Heute schicke ich dir eine Seite notwendiger Wortschatz**

wegen des Genetivs ebenfalls richtig.

Comment: Ich hab Wortschatz immer nur im Singular gesehen...

Comment: Ich kann mir Wortschätze durchaus vorstellen, aber ich glaube, dass hier der Wortschatz gemeint ist.