# zwei Millionen Menschen

Tags: grammar-identification

> zwei Millionen Menschen

Is the "Millionen" measurement a noun in the above phrase?

Comment: Very similar [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/11341/1696).

Comment: Please don't post link if you can copy-paste the remote content. What if the remote side goes down?

Comment: Ok I will try not to happen next time

Comment: Why not copy-paste the relevant content right now into current question?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is a noun in the above phrase.

Proof lies in the dictionaries:
https://www.dwds.de/wb/Million and
https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Million

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The pattern is

> <*number*> <*unit*> <*measured item(s)*>

Examples are

> 80 Gramm Schinken
>   Zwei Liter Milch
>   Vier Tassen Kaffee
>   Drei Teelöffel Salz
>   Zwei Stück Zucker
>   Sechs Dutzend Eier
>   Zwei Millionen Euro

In the last examples you see that the unit is a number-nouns, but they still are used as units

Comment: This lacks an explanation, in which cases the *plural* for the unit should be preferred, as would apply to *Millionen*.

Comment: @guidot: Very easy: All units need to be in singular if *<number>* equals to 1 (i.e. "ein" or "eine"). In all other cases the unit has to be in plural. All units in my examples are in plural.

Comment: Seems an oversimplification looking at [that answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/41742/1696): e. g. *sieben Glas Bier*

Comment: Zwei Millionen Menschen könnte aber Zweimillionen sein, so wie in Zweimillionensiebenhundertvier Menschen oder Zweihundert Euro (Zwei Hundert Euro ja sicherlich nicht, oder nur in sehr seltenen Ausnahmen).