# "Ein halbes Kilo Kaffee" - welcher Kasus ist "Kaffee" hier?

Tags: grammatical-case

Ich habe keine Ahnung welcher Kasus ist "Kaffee" in dieser Phrase: "ein halbes Kilo Kaffee". Ich dachte, es sollte Genitiv sein, aber warum denn nicht "ein halbes Kilo Kaffees"?

Comment: Englische Antwort hier: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11341/what-kind-of-construction-is-eine-tasse-kaffee?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es gibt im Deutschen im Prinzip zwei Möglichkeiten, Mengenangaben oder Behältniszusammenhänge anzugeben:

1. *Partitiver Genitiv* - Hier steht das Ding, dessen Menge angegeben wird, im Genitiv - das ist eine relativ altmodische (oder auch "poetische") Art, solche Sachverhalte wiederzugeben. Heute gilt sie als veraltet.

   > Er trank ein Glas süßen Weines

   (*Glas* im Akkusativ, wie im Satzzusammenhang erforderlich, *Wein* **immer** im Genitiv)

   > Sie gab der Tasse arabischen Kaffees eine kräftige Portion Zucker zu

   (*Tasse* im Dativ, wie im Satzzusammenhang erforderlich, *Kaffee* im Genitiv)
2. Kasusangleichung an das zugehörige Nomen - Hier steht das Ding, dessen Menge angegeben wird, im Kasus der Mengeneinheit (oder des Behälters)

   > Er trank ein Glas süßen Wein

   (*Glas* und *Wein* im Akkusativ)

   > Sie gab der Tasse arabischem Kaffee eine kräftige Portion Zucker zu

   (*Tasse* im Dativ, wie im Satzzusammenhang erforderlich, *Kaffee* im gleichen Kasus)

In beiden Fällen müssen natürlich die attributiven Adjektive im jeweils passenden Kasus stehen.

In modernem Deutsch wird (sehr) überwiegend (2) verwendet. Der partitive Genitiv, wie in (1) ist praktisch ausgestorben und findet sich nur noch in alter Literatur und in der Lyrik.

Dein Beispiel scheint im Nominativ zu stehen und daher ist nach (2) auch der Kaffee im Nominativ.